# Behavior: Bad operation on memory or Memory leak C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm new in C++ and i'm facing such an **Error**:

> Behavior: Bad operation on memory or Memory leak    at:
>   MyInteger::isPrime(int) (MyInteger.cpp:72)    by: main (main.cpp:23)
>   at: MyInteger::isPrime(int) (MyInteger.cpp:59)

What is that suppose to mean and how could i fix this ? I tried to use `valgrind` but seems a bit complicated for the freshman.

```
 //MyInteger.cpp
        bool MyInteger::isPrime(int z){
            int i,flag1;
            if(z == 1){
                flag1 = 1;
            }
            for(i = 2; i < z; i++){
                if(z % i == 0)
                {
                    flag1 = 1; 
                    break;
                }else flag1 = 0;
            }

            if(flag1 == 1){
                return false;
            }else return true;
            }  

    //MyInteger.hpp  
    class MyInteger{
       public:
       static bool isPrime(int);
    };  

    //main.cpp  

    int main{
      const string words[3][2] = {"not even", "even",
                                    "not odd", "odd",
                                    "not prime", "prime"};  
        ..............................
        ..............................
        ...............................
        cout << "Integer "  << b << " is: ";
        cout << words[0][MyInteger::isEven(b)] << ", ";
        cout << words[1][MyInteger::isOdd(b)] << ", ";
        cout << words[2][MyInteger::isPrime(b)] << ".\n";
    }
```

Comment: I see no `static` keyword here, and I see no pointer here. So it absolutely caused by the caller of this function, not this function. You better debug it instead

Comment: "I can't put the whole code here" - no one wants the full code. What we want is a [mcve]. A minimal example is usually a *new* program that you create specifically to ask the question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl gotcha

Comment: @NguyễnSanhĐìnhAnh i did edited the question, could you take a look please. I called it in main.cpp file

Comment: `words` looks like an array? In that case the aboce call makes no real sense except you stored the text you want to print in there e.g. `words[0][0]` contains "Number is odd". Hoe do you initialize this array? Please provide enough code to help you.

Comment: @Dr.raider the function return bool value, And you try to iterate an array with bool? I didn't know if it's a thing. Can you show me how you initiate the array `word`

Comment: @Yastanub i did updated the code

Comment: This is not a valid C++ program. Please make sure every program you post here does what you say it does, in this case compiles and runs **as is**.

Answer (score 0):

It is seem that your function `isPrime` is private function, which could not be call in main()
This code work for me

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MyInteger
{
   public: static bool isPrime(int);
};
bool MyInteger::isPrime(int z)
{
    int i,flag1;
    if(z == 1){
        flag1 = 1;
    }
    for(i = 2; i < z; i++){
        if(z % i == 0)
        {
            flag1 = 1; 
            break;
        }else flag1 = 0;
    }

    if(flag1 == 1){
        return false;
    }else return true;
} 
int main()
{
    const string words[3][2] = {"not even", "even",
                                    "not odd", "odd",
                                    "not prime", "prime"};  
    int b=2;
    cout << "Integer "  << b << " is: ";

    cout << words[2][MyInteger::isPrime(b)] << ".\n";
}
```

Output

```
Integer 2 is: not prime.
```

Comment: yeah it is public, i just forgot to mention it here. And my code is works fine, compiles and gives the correct result. I just got the above warning about memory leak and want to fix it.

Comment: @Dr.raider `Behavior: Bad operation on memory or Memory leak at: MyInteger::isPrime(int) (MyInteger.cpp:72) by: main (main.cpp:23)
at: MyInteger::isPrime(int) (MyInteger.cpp:59)` can you specify which line is this. Like no one know which is MyInteger.cpp:72 or main.cpp:23. And just a wild guess, try to initialize `flag1` at the beginning of your function